# Checking if form closed from backgroundworker VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, dispose

I have a few tasks for my backGroundWorker.The code is as follows:

```
     Private Sub bgworker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgworker.DoWork
    connecttosrv.showDialog
    Dim p() As Process
    p = Process.GetProcessesByName("mssqlserver")
    If p.Count > 0 Then
    Else
        Try
            Dim p1 As Process
            p1 = Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C net start mssqlserver")
            p1.WaitForExit()
        Catch ex As Exception
            err = ex.ToString
        End Try
    End If
     Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data source=" & My.Settings.IP & "," & My.Settings.Port & ";Network Library=DBMSSOCN;initial catalog=offpodb;User id=" & My.Settings.username & ";Password=" & My.Settings.password & ";")
        con.open
```

Now let me explain my scenario . As u can see, the bgWorker tries to connect to my database using **IP,Port,Username and Password** that are stored in **MY.SETTINGS**.

The values of **My.Settings.IP,Password,Usernmae,Port** are all empty on startup.Their values get added from another form(connecttosrv in this case,this form has textboxes where user enter IP,Port,Password,Username).

Look at the bgWorker's code.The first line is :

```
 connecttosrv.ShowDialog
```

The other codes are executed after ConnectToSrv has showed.But as mentioned,bgWorkder tries to connect to the database getting required details from **My.Settings** , and **My.Settings** gets the values from ConnectToSrv form. So, as per my code, the bgWorker will execute other codes after it's done showing the ConnectToSrv form.This will cause the **SQLCONNECTION** to fail to connect as **MY.SETTINGS** values will be empty.

So the help i want can be said as either :

**1• Is there anyway to make the BackGroundWorker check if ConnectToSrv form has closed so that My.Settings gets all required values for SQL Connection**

or

**2• Is it possible to pause the backgroundWorker when the 2nd form(ConnectTOSrv) has showed and resume it again when the form has closed. (After doing a bit of research, i found that i can set-up the BgWorker to check if Form IsDisposed but i don't know how to use/apply it)**

Comment: Why a downvote???

Comment: Incidentally, if you used an [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) then you would not have to worry about characters like ";" in the username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Form.ShowDialog, the code after it wouldn't be executed until the form is closed. I think it's not the case with a BackgroundWorker.

Try calling connecttosrv.ShowDialog() exactly before bgworker.RunWorkerAsync, so the code in bgworker_DoWork -which is the event raised when RunWorkerAsync is called- woudln't be executed until that dialog is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Do not perform UI operations in the background worker thread. Execute `connecttosrv.showDialog` before starting the  background worker.

```
connecttosrv.showDialog
bgworker.RunWorkerAsync()
```

Remove `connecttosrv.showDialog` from `bgworker_DoWork`.

To be thread-safe, pass all the reuired paramters to the backround worker as parameter

```
Public Class MyParameters
    Public Property Prop1 As String
    Public Property Prop2 As Integer
    ...
End Class
```

Pass the parameters

```
connecttosrv.showDialog

Dim params = new MyParameters()
params.Prop1 = "hello"
params.Prop2 = 7

bgworker.RunWorkerAsync(params)
```

In the worker method, you can access them with

```
Private Sub bgworker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object,
    ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgworker.DoWork

    Dim params = DirectCast(e.Argument, MyParameters)
```